# How to perform large computations on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop, bigdata

I have 2 tables in Hive: `user` and `item` and I am trying to calculate cosine similarity between 2 features of each table for a cartesian product between the 2 tables, i.e. Cross Join.

There are around 20000 `users` and 5000 `items` resulting in `100 million` rows of calculation. I am running the compute using Scala Spark on Hive Cluster with 12 cores.

The code goes a little something like this:

```
val pairs = userDf.crossJoin(itemDf).repartition(100)
val results = pairs.mapPartitions(computeScore)  // computeScore is a function to compute the similarity scores I need
```

The Spark job will always fail due to memory issues (GC Allocation Failure) on the Hadoop cluster. If I reduce the computation to around 10 million, it will definitely work - under 15 minutes.

How do I compute the whole set without increasing the hardware specifications? I am fine if the job takes longer to run and does not fail halfway.

Comment: May be you can try with repartition(500) or more.

Comment: What are the specifications of your cluster? Why _100_?

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look in the Spark documentation you will see that spark uses different strategies for data management. These policies are enabled by the user via configurations in the spark configuration files or directly in the code or script.

Below the documentation about data management policies:
[image: data management policies]

"MEMORY_AND_DISK" policy would be good for you because if the data (RDD) does not fit in the ram then the remaining partitons will be stored in the hard disk. But this strategy can be slow if you have to access the hard drive often.

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps of doing that: 
1. Check the expected Data volume after cross join and divide this by 200 as spark.sql.shuffle.partitions by default comes as 200. It has to be more than 1 GB raw data to each partition. 
2. Calculate each row size and multiply with another table row count , you will be able to estimated the rough Volume. The process will work much better in Parquet in comparison to CSV file
3. spark.sql.shuffle.partitions needs to be set based on Total Data Volume/500 MB
4. spark.shuffle.minNumPartitionsToHighlyCompress needs to set a little less than Shuffle Partition
5. Bucketize the source parquet data based on the joining column for both of the files/tables
6. Provide a High Spark Executor Memory and Manage the Java Heap memory too considering the heap space